# Why is this error coming : 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'percent'?

Tags: python, psutil

Actually, I am building a simple personal assistant using Python
I have imported the `psutil` module. But, why is `psutil.sensors_battery()` returning None?

```
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    pc = battery.percent
    speak(f'sir, system is at {pc} percent battery level')
```

Comment: There is no answer to that @y_159

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=sensors#psutil.sensors_battery) shows that the return value is either a named tuple or `None`.

You should cater for that in your code:

```py
import psutil

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
if battery:
    pc = battery.percent
    speak(f'sir, system is at {pc} percent battery level')
else:
    speak('sir, I cannot determine the battery level')
```